# How to remove the left search panel on a list item edit form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, form

How can I remove the annoying search panel that shows up on the left when editing a list item form (see image below)?  I've tried using "Launch in Dialog" but that gives the user on old version of the edit form that we don't want to use.

[image: annoying search panel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - You can't.

Long-ish answer - Currently, Microsoft(MS) is not allowing any customizations for the "Modern" lists and libraries experience. So, custom css, jslink , script injection etc won't work on these pages.

Only option right now is to keep using Classic(old) SharePoint experience if you want to remove that annoying left panel thing, else you will have to wait for couple of months for MS to allow customization on the "Modern" experience.

[Allow Javascript customization and CSS branding/theming in the new Document Library & List Experience](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th)